# Why does the Force do the bidding of the Jedi and Sith?

Tags: star-wars

The Force has a mind of its own, given how it lashed back at Darth Plagueis and Sidious by creating Anakin through the midi-chlorians but how come it can be manipulated in the first place to do what you want? I can understand reaching out to it so you can save a life or do something important but how come it can also be used for trivial tasks, like the the time Anakin used it to move fruit?

EDIT: Anakin being created by the Force in response to Darth Plagueis' meddling is not confirmed again due to the sources now being Legends but there are canon sources that confirm the Force has a mind of its own, for instance, The Father, The Son and The Daughter.

Comment: It's all about the midi-chlorians, dude.

Comment: You're asking two distinct questions here. You should ask the second part as a separate question.

Comment: I think they are related, if the Force chooses to do the Jedi's request, then it can decline it, if the Force is forced to do the request, then there's no denial, it all depends on the Jedi's skill.

Comment: Two questions; "**How does the Force work?**" and "**Has the Force ever refused to obey a Force user?**". Certainly related, but not the same question

Comment: Ok, I agree with that, I'll make another question for the second one.

Comment: You might want to note that the idea of Anakin being the result of Plageuis and Sidious' meddling with the Force is not officially canon.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read it was, at least in Legends, Plageuis was utterly scared of that and went so far as to spy on Anakin when he was on Coruscant.

Comment: Legends is non-canon, by definition.

Comment: “how come it can also be used for trivial tasks, like the the time Anakin used it to move fruit?” — Maybe it was a really important kumquat.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - He was doing it to impress a hot girl. Maybe the Force is a bro.

Comment: *I heard Yoda talking about midi-chlorians. I've been wondering...what are midi-chlorians?*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - that Kumquat resulted in Luke Skywalker. I'd say it was important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a matter of bee-hive logic. I mean, the Force is this big thing that ties everything together, but it's not really "conscious." If you have mitichlorians, you can manipulate the Force, and if the Force thinks a person needs to exist, it makes one (like Anakin) with a ton of mitichlorians. It seems to me that the mitichlorians are like a stamp at the bar door: if you have the stamp, you can do whatever you want in the bar. If you don't have the stamp, you can't do anything. The Force owns the bar and is the bouncer, and it might grab people off the street and stamp them just because it wants them in the club. Granted, it's not a perfect metaphor, but the point is: the Force decides who gets mitichlorians, then the people decide what to do with them. Maybe they do nothing. Maybe they move fruit. Maybe they Force-hover up to look in girls' windows on Coruscant, we don't know, but whatever they do is up to them. The Force is kind of like a god in that it gives the people all the stuff it needs them to have, but then it kind of just lets them do whatever they want with it. Like, God never took away someone's hands because the person was doing jazz hands too often. Poseidon never vanished all the water because people were just splashing each other with it. It's like a bee-hive: most things can't come in, but if you get in, nobody pays attention to what you're doing. You could just loaf around and do nothing and you wouldn't get kicked out because once you're in, you're in, no matter what foolishness you decide to get into with that privilege.

Comment: Do you have any actual evidence from the source material as to this? This is more or less my interpretation as well, but I'm not sure that there is any actual canon evidence of this.

Comment: My evidence is simply logic. Seeing as we know the Force does obey the Jedi and the Sith even in silly little things, we must assume this is the reason because nothing else makes sense. No, I do not have concrete proof from any canon sources that this is the answer.